# Mysterious Matrix Norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces

Given a matrix $M$,
does anyone know the name and the definition of the following norm?
$$
\|M\|_*
$$

Thanks in advance,
Francesco.

Comment: You have given no definition, but a symbol.

Comment: It's the lower star norm, of course.

Comment: Perhaps it's the [nuclear norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Schatten_norms).

Comment: Given an innerproduct $\langle ,\rangle_*$ then $\| \cdot \|_*$  is meant to be the norm with respect to $\langle ,\rangle_*$, thats the agreement in our numerical anaylsis course, but that says not much more than your posting at all..

Comment: You can see: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/102580/how-do-you-compute-the-dual-norm-of-an-induced-norm-on-a-subspace-of-a-finite-di/103075#103075

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the Schatten norm.
It's defined like:

$ \lVert A \rVert_* := \text{tr}(\sqrt{AA^T}) $ with tr is the trace of the matrix and $A^T$ is the transpose.

In other case, there's the matrix norm defined like
 (for $A \in M_{m \text{ row }, n \text{ column }}$):

$ \lVert A \rVert_p = \max_{x \neq 0} \left\{ \frac{\lvert A x \rvert_p}{\lvert x \rvert_p} , x \in K^n \right\}$

where the $ \lvert \cdot \rvert_p$ is the vector $p$-norm.

It really depends on the notation :)

Comment: yeah, I think that the schatten norm would be a good fit based on the context where I found it! thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to give a bit more context to get an exact answer - there are plenty of different ways to come up with norms on matrices.  However, there are two primary classical ones:

1) The Euclidean Norm: view an $n\times m$ matrix as an $mn$-long vector. Then the usual vector norm induces a norm on the matrix.

2) The Operator Norm: $n\times m$ matrices can also be viewed as linear operators $\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$, for which we have the operator norm:
$$
\|A\|_{op}:=\inf\{c>0\mid \|A\vec{v}\|\leq c\|\vec{v}\|\text{ for all }\vec{v}\in\mathbb{R}^m\}=\inf_{\|\vec{v}\|=1}\|A\vec{v}\|,
$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is understood as the usual vector norm in whichever vector space is appropriate at the moment.

I should point out, however, that all norms on finite vector spaces are equivalent.  So, even though various norms will likely disagree on a given matrix... the topology that they induce on the set of matrices will be the same.